# LLVM CommandLine: how to reset arguments?

Tags: command-line, llvm

I have two static libs that use [LLVM command line](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html) to parse arguments:

```
// lib1
void main(int argc, const char **argv) {

  cl::opt<bool>LibOption1( ... ) // arg1
  cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv, "lib1\n");
}
```

.

```
// lib2
void main(int argc, const char **argv) {

  // need to reset arguments list here ..

  cl::opt<bool>LibOption2( ... ) // arg2
  cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv, "lib2\n"); // crash here!
}
```

The app is linked against two this libs and they parse arguments just fine if having only 1 lib in the app and crash while parsing arguments if having both libs in the app.

It seems that in lines with `// arg` argument is added in some global static list (?) of arguments and this makes them have mixed arguments list and affect to each other.

Is there any opportunity to reset that global list before declaring arguments?

**PS.** I've found that static arguments list in `CommandLine.cpp`:

```
/// RegisteredOptionList - This is the list of the command line options that
/// have statically constructed themselves.
static Option *RegisteredOptionList = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

What is `void main` supposed to be? `main` returns `int`, and in any case libraries can't provide a main. If this is in some namespace, still please don't write `void main`.

The global list is supposed to be a feature, so that each library can provide its own (differently-namespaced) arguments. The library should *not* be calling `cl::ParseCommandLineOptions` itself; only the true main function should do that. Additionally, in a library it doesn't make sense for `cl::opt` to be a local variable, because then it only exists for the duration of that function. (If you are the application, then you can arrange for `cl::ParseCommandLineOptions` to be called before the `cl::opt`s expire).

Comment: function names and return values do not make sense in my case. let's think functions are `func1` and `func2`. The fact is both libs use cl:: to parse arguments. In most cases there are no problems since cl:: list init is used once in tool as main() function is declared once and parsing happens in the very beginning. Imagine there are 2 functions that perform arguments parsing and they should handle different arguments and both use cl::