# How to avoid LLVM's Support CommandLine leaking library arguments?

Tags: c++, command-line-interface, llvm

I've been working on a compiler for a language of mine and wanted to utilize the LLVM Support Library [CommandLine](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html) to handle argument parsing.

I have only added two simple declarations:

```
static cl::opt<std::string>
OutputFilename("o", cl::desc("Output filename"), cl::value_desc("filename"));

static cl::list<std::string> 
InputFilenames("i", cl::desc("Input files"), cl::value_desc("filenames"), cl::OneOrMore);
```

I then add the usual call in main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv, " My compiler\n");

...
```

The problem is very apparent when passing `-help` to my program:

```
General options:

  -aarch64-neon-syntax             - Choose style of NEON code to emit from AArch64 backend:
    =generic                       -   Emit generic NEON assembly
    =apple                         -   Emit Apple-style NEON assembly
  -cppfname=<function name>        - Specify the name of the generated function
  -cppfor=<string>                 - Specify the name of the thing to generate
  -cppgen                          - Choose what kind of output to generate
    =program                       -   Generate a complete program
    =module                        -   Generate a module definition
    =contents                      -   Generate contents of a module
    =function                      -   Generate a function definition
    =functions                     -   Generate all function definitions
    =inline                        -   Generate an inline function
    =variable                      -   Generate a variable definition
    =type                          -   Generate a type definition
  -debugger-tune                   - Tune debug info for a particular debugger
    =gdb                           -   gdb
    =lldb                          -   lldb
    =sce                           -   SCE targets (e.g. PS4)
  -disable-spill-fusing            - Disable fusing of spill code into instructions
  -enable-implicit-null-checks     - Fold null checks into faulting memory operations
  -enable-load-pre                 - 
  -enable-objc-arc-opts            - enable/disable all ARC Optimizations
  -enable-scoped-noalias           - 
  -enable-tbaa                     - 
  -exhaustive-register-search      - Exhaustive Search for registers bypassing the depth and interference cutoffs of last chance recoloring
  -gpsize=<uint>                   - Global Pointer Addressing Size.  The default size is 8.
  -i=<filenames>                   - Input files
  -imp-null-check-page-size=<uint> - The page size of the target in bytes
  -join-liveintervals              - Coalesce copies (default=true)
  -limit-float-precision=<uint>    - Generate low-precision inline sequences for some float libcalls
  -merror-missing-parenthesis      - Error for missing parenthesis around predicate registers
  -merror-noncontigious-register   - Error for register names that aren't contigious
  -mfuture-regs                    - Enable future registers
  -mips16-constant-islands         - Enable mips16 constant islands.
  -mips16-hard-float               - Enable mips16 hard float.
  -mno-compound                    - Disable looking for compound instructions for Hexagon
  -mno-ldc1-sdc1                   - Expand double precision loads and stores to their single precision counterparts
  -mno-pairing                     - Disable looking for duplex instructions for Hexagon
  -mwarn-missing-parenthesis       - Warn for missing parenthesis around predicate registers
  -mwarn-noncontigious-register    - Warn for register names that arent contigious
  -mwarn-sign-mismatch             - Warn for mismatching a signed and unsigned value
  -nvptx-sched4reg                 - NVPTX Specific: schedule for register pressue
  -o=<filename>                    - Output filename
  -print-after-all                 - Print IR after each pass
  -print-before-all                - Print IR before each pass
  -print-machineinstrs=<pass-name> - Print machine instrs
  -regalloc                        - Register allocator to use
    =default                       -   pick register allocator based on -O option
    =fast                          -   fast register allocator
    =greedy                        -   greedy register allocator
    =pbqp                          -   PBQP register allocator
  -rewrite-map-file=<filename>     - Symbol Rewrite Map
  -rng-seed=<seed>                 - Seed for the random number generator
  -stackmap-version=<int>          - Specify the stackmap encoding version (default = 1)
  -stats                           - Enable statistics output from program (available with Asserts)
  -time-passes                     - Time each pass, printing elapsed time for each on exit
  -verify-debug-info               - 
  -verify-dom-info                 - Verify dominator info (time consuming)
  -verify-loop-info                - Verify loop info (time consuming)
  -verify-regalloc                 - Verify during register allocation
  -verify-region-info              - Verify region info (time consuming)
  -verify-scev                     - Verify ScalarEvolution's backedge taken counts (slow)
  -x86-asm-syntax                  - Choose style of code to emit from X86 backend:
    =att                           -   Emit AT&T-style assembly
    =intel                         -   Emit Intel-style assembly

Generic Options:

  -help                            - Display available options (-help-hidden for more)
  -help-list                       - Display list of available options (-help-list-hidden for more)
  -version                         - Display the version of this program
```

I would obviously like to cut down the noise to show only the relevant command line options I have exposed.

I realize the [CommandLine](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html) utility is utilizing global variables and [template metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) and my problem is probably due to linking with LLVM statically.

I have found several links that seem to touch on the issue, but nothing concrete as a solution other then possibly dynamically linking to LLVM.

---

- [LLVM CommandLine: how to reset arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078018/llvm-commandline-how-to-reset-arguments)
- [LLVMdev: Command line options being put in Target backend libraries](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/llvm-dev/D4h_ZZzqcCU/W7oMfk9JP1oJ)
- [Bugzilla 8860: command-line argument parser provides too many options when building with --enable-shared](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8860)

---

I am running on OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.1

I installed llvm as follows:

```
git clone http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git
git clone http://llvm.org/git/clang.git llvm/tools/clang
git clone http://llvm.org/git/clang-tools-extra.git llvm/tools/clang/tools/extra
git clone http://llvm.org/git/compiler-rt.git llvm/projects/compiler-rt
git clone http://llvm.org/git/libcxx.git llvm/projects/libcxx
git clone http://llvm.org/git/libcxxabi.git llvm/projects/libcxxabi

mkdir build_llvm
cd build_llvm && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=prefix=/usr/local/llvm ../llvm
make
```

The relevant portions of my Makefile:

```
LLVMCONFIG = llvm-config
CPPFLAGS = `$(LLVMCONFIG) --cxxflags` -std=c++11
LDFLAGS = `$(LLVMCONFIG) --ldflags` -lpthread -ldl -lz -lncurses -rdynamic
LIBS = `$(LLVMCONFIG) --libs`

%.o: %.cpp
    clang++ -I /usr/local/llvm/include -c $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@

mycompiler: $(OBJECTS)
    clang++ -I /usr/local/llvm/include -g $^ $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see, the best you can do is to put all of your options into particular categories and use [void llvm::cl::HideUnrelatedOptions(ArrayRef     Categories)](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm_1_1cl.html#a75ca2a54f061c1aa700793458074bfee) (or [cl::HideUnrelatedOptions(cl::OptionCategory &   Category)](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm_1_1cl.html#a75ca2a54f061c1aa700793458074bfee) if you have only a single category). The documentation indicates that clang uses it to get control over the command line options, though I haven't checked in the clang source to see if that is really true.

Comment: I ran into that as well in my search and figured it may be the only option for now apart from modifying the source myself.  I upvoted for the suggestion and I will probably use that in the short term while I'm focused on other things.  I will leave unanswered for a little while and hope this question can help others looking at using the API.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Geoff Reedy's answer worked great for me so I accepted his answer, however, I wanted to give more details on how you set it up, as well as some other information I found.

As before I have my options in declarative form above my `main` function however I have added a declarative `OptionCategory` and have included this in the declarations of each option in that category:

```
cl::OptionCategory 
CompilerCategory("Compiler Options", "Options for controlling the compilation process.");

static cl::opt<std::string>
OutputFilename("o", cl::desc("Output filename"), cl::value_desc("filename"), cl::cat(CompilerCategory));

static cl::list<std::string> 
InputFilenames("i", cl::desc("Input files"), cl::value_desc("filenames"), cl::OneOrMore, cl::cat(CompilerCategory));
```

Then I have the call to `HideUnrelatedOptions` within `main` just before `ParseCommandLineOptions`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cl::HideUnrelatedOptions( CompilerCategory );
    cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv, " My compiler\n");

...
```

Now my `OPTIONS` output looks much better:

```
OPTIONS:

Compiler Options:
Options for controlling the compilation process.

  -i=<filenames> - Input files
  -o=<filename>  - Output filename

Generic Options:

  -help          - Display available options (-help-hidden for more)
  -help-list     - Display list of available options (-help-list-hidden for more)
  -version       - Display the version of this program
```

This basically marks all options as `cl::ReallyHidden` so they do not even show up with `-help-hidden` :).

The other useful information I found was on the [CommandLine Library Manual](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html#the-cl-getregisteredoptions-function).

I know LLVM is in constant flux so just in case the page is gone in the future here is the example:

> ```
> using namespace llvm;
> int main(int argc, char **argv) {
>   cl::OptionCategory AnotherCategory("Some options");
>
>   StringMap<cl::Option*> Map;
>   cl::getRegisteredOptions(Map);
>
>   //Unhide useful option and put it in a different category
>   assert(Map.count("print-all-options") > 0);
>   Map["print-all-options"]->setHiddenFlag(cl::NotHidden);
>   Map["print-all-options"]->setCategory(AnotherCategory);
>
>   //Hide an option we don't want to see
>   assert(Map.count("enable-no-infs-fp-math") > 0);
>   Map["enable-no-infs-fp-math"]->setHiddenFlag(cl::Hidden);
>
>   //Change --version to --show-version
>   assert(Map.count("version") > 0);
>   Map["version"]->setArgStr("show-version");
>
>   //Change --help description
>   assert(Map.count("help") > 0);
>   Map["help"]->setDescription("Shows help");
>
>   cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv, "This is a small program to demo the LLVM CommandLine API");
>   ...
> }
> ```

This basically shows the power of the system and demonstrates how to modify specific options however you wish.

Comment: do you know whether it's possible to hide the "generic options" section?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for reviving this thread from long ago. However, I was facing the *exact* same problem and found the two existing answers invaluable. Thank you @geoff-reedy and @matthew-sanders! As I followed the existing answers' advice, I ran into a pretty big problem:

If I invoked the program with `-help-hidden` the category headers (even though they were unrelated) were still printed even though none of the options contained therein were displayed. It made for very curious output.

So, I dug in a little bit and came up with an alternate solution based on the awesome, existing answers. For posterity I will post it here in case it helps someone (probably a future version of me)!

Instead of declaring the command line values that I wanted my program to accept as file-scoped global variables (the typical advice for using the CommandLine library), I had to create them as variables local to *some* scope. That essentially delayed the options' addition to the `GlobalParser` object declared in the library's implementation until that scope was elaborated. Then, before that scope was elaborated, I invoked `llvm::cl::ResetCommandLineParser`. That removed all the leaked command-line options from the `GlobalParser`. Then, when the constructor for *my* options were encountered, they were the only command-line options available in the `GlobalParser`.

Finally, I specified a "discard" `llvm::raw_ostream` (`llvm::raw_null_ostream`) to pass to the `Errs` parameter of the invocation of `llvm::cl::ParseCommandLineOptions`. The presence of an argument for `Errs` in the call to `llvm::cl::ParseCommandLineOptions` forces the library not to terminate the program if there are errors parsing the arguments. I specified a null output stream because I wanted to generate my own error messages, but specifying a real stream would give the same signal to `llvm::cl::ParseCommandLineOptions` *and* allow you to print the parser-generate error messages for the user.

Of course, there were problems left to solve. Most notably, this approach meant that I had to specify and handle `-help` (or `-help-hidden`) myself. It was relatively easy to do that using the `llvm::cl::PrintHelpMessage()` function. Next, I had to handle the case where `llvm::cl::Required` options were not properly specified by the user. Handling this problem was also straightforward -- `cl::llvm::ParseCommandLineOptions` will return `false` when there is an error parsing the command-line arguments.

One of the benefits of declaring the command-line option variables at the global scope is that other functions can access them easily. With the approach that I took, this feature is no longer available. Although I did not handle that problem in the code I wrote, it might be possible to write a set of helper functions that retrieve the values of the command-line option variables from static, function-local storage.

For reference, here is the code that I ended up writing:

```
[[noreturn]] void usage() {
  llvm::cl::PrintHelpMessage();
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {  
  llvm::raw_null_ostream raw_discard{};
  llvm::cl::ResetCommandLineParser();

  llvm::cl::OptionCategory SeePlusPlusCategory(
      "See Plus Plus Options",
      "Options for controlling the behavior of See Plus Plus.");
  llvm::cl::opt<std::string> SourceCodeFilename(
      llvm::cl::Positional, llvm::cl::desc("<source file>"), llvm::cl::Required,
      llvm::cl::cat(SeePlusPlusCategory));
  llvm::cl::opt<bool> SuppressLineNumbers(
      "nl", llvm::cl::desc("Suppress line numbers in output."),
      llvm::cl::cat(SeePlusPlusCategory));
  llvm::cl::opt<bool> Help(
      "help", llvm::cl::desc("Display available options"),
      llvm::cl::ValueDisallowed, llvm::cl::cat(SeePlusPlusCategory));

  llvm::cl::HideUnrelatedOptions(SeePlusPlusCategory);
  if (!llvm::cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv, "", &raw_discard)) {
    usage();
  }

  if (Help) {
    usage();
  }

  // Program continues from here.
}
```

Again, thank you to Matthew and Geoff for their great answers. I hope that what I wrote above helps someone else in the future as much as their answers helped me!